# Remote-desktop with freerdp inactive timeout timeout

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, raspberry-pi, thin-client

So I have a raspberry pi that boots to a RDP session in to a virtual machine using the program freerdp. It is closing the session if it sits inactive for about a min. Is there a way to shut this off completely or make the timer really long?

Answer (score 0):

try following here: http://www.howtogeek.com/141157/how-to-configure-your-raspberry-pi-for-remote-shell-desktop-and-file-transfer/

This way you aren't using any freerdp hacks and are doing it the proper way.